# Save Event in Calendar

Tags: html, database, fullcalendar

I have this all code in HTML because is for a website that only I can embed HMTL code but when I refresh each time the website, the calendar doesn't save the events. What can I do?. Can I add something to fix it? Sorry I am a noob in all this in website code, so I don't know what I can do to fix it. Thanks for helping me

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<div id="page">
  <div class="page-header">
  <Center><h1>Reservation Server 1</h1></center>
  </div>
  <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>

<div class="bubble">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
      <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style> 
#page {
  max-width: 960px; padding: 0 15px; margin: 40px auto;
  @media (max-height: 790px) {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
.page-header h1 { .text-center; font-weight: 100; }

.input, select {
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
.btn {
  padding: .2em .8em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(239,239,239,1) 60%,rgba(225,223,226,1) 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat; // fix for firefox
}

.bubble {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fff; padding: 15px;
  width: 420px;
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;

  .close {
    position: absolute; font-size: 24px; line-height: 1;
    padding: 0 5px;
    right: 5px; top: 5px;
  }
}

.bubble {
  @border-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid @border-color;
  .arrow, .arrow:after {
    position: absolute; height: 0; width: 0; font-size: 0; .horizontal-border(transparent, 10px);
  }
  &-top, &-bottom {
    .arrow {
      left: 50%; margin-left: -10px;
    }
    .arrow:after {
      content: ''; left: -10px;
    }
  }
  &-top {
    .arrow {
      border-top: @border-color 10px solid; top: 100%;
    }
    .arrow:after {
      border-top: #FFF  10px solid; bottom: 1px;
    }
  }
  &-bottom {
    .arrow {
      border-bottom: @border-color 10px solid; bottom: 100%;
    }
    .arrow:after {
      border-bottom: #FFF  10px solid; top: 1px;
    }
  }
}


.form-group {
  .clearfix; padding-bottom: 8px;
  &>label {
    float: left; width: 4em; text-align: right; padding-right: 5px;
  }
  &>input, &>.input-wrapper {
    margin-left: 4em;
    display: block;
  }
}


.btn-delete {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: none;
  .text-danger;
  &:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}

.usage { margin-top: 10px; }
</style>
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.3.1/lang-all.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() { // document ready

  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    defaultTimedEventDuration: '01:30',
    allDaySlot: false,
    scrollTime: '14:00',
    businessHours: {
      start: '14:00',
      end: '24:00',
    },
    lang: /^en-/.test(navigator.language) ? 'en' : 'zh-cn',
    eventOverlap: function(stillEvent, movingEvent) {
      return true;
    },
    events: [{
      title: '技术部周例会',
      start: '2015-05-22T15:00+08:00'
    }, {
      title: '运营部',
      start: '2015-05-22T12:00+08:00'
    }],
    editable: false,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end) {
      var duration = (end - start) /1000;
      if(duration == 1800) {
        // set default duration to 1 hr.
        end = start.add(30, 'mins');
        return calendar.fullCalendar('select', start, end);
      }
      var title = prompt('NAMES TEAMS EXAMPLE: NAC VS REUNITED');
      var eventData;
      if (title && title.trim()) {
        eventData = {
          title: title,
          start: start,
          end: end
        };
        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData);
      }
      calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      var start = moment(event.start).fromNow();
      element.attr('title', start);
    },
    loading: function() {
      
    }
  });

});   
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: In order to save the events, you need some kind of database to store the data. Now what is happening is your application(HTML page) is able to get the user input but it is not having code or anything to save the data. Probably look into that.

Comment: How can I do? Sorry I am new, but I learn fast

Comment: Well that is bit complicated since you are a new developer. You need a backend program (JAVA,C#, Python, Php) that will get the data from HTML page and process the data and store it in a database(Best option of Database would be MySQL). So you would need to do all those things.

Comment: Php file. Can you help me with codes in php file?

Comment: Sorry I am Java developer I have no exp on Php. Probably you can post it in a freelancing site, they would do that for you if you pay them.

Comment: now it is easy to use cloud database like https://neon.tech which is serverless postgressql